# Model binding problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have this code

```
public class Room
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public List<person> people { get; set;}        
}
}

public class person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to bind a list of person and place it in the room object

I create my textboxes for person name and I name them people[index].Name
I can bind them to a list of person (by removing people) but I cant bind them to the Rooms people object. Is there a way?

Comment: show us your view. you should be using `EditorFor`. are you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I figured out the answer

In mvc 2 you need an index and in 3 you don't (wrt Non-Sequential Indices). [This](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) site provides some insight

I'm sorry I never give you guys enough information to answer this question. I work with multiple solutions it's difficult for me to keep track right now.

Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

```
public ActionResult([Bind(Prefix="people")]person p)
```

Comment: and change person to Person since its a class name